# Graph API v11.0

Tags: react-native, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk-next

I recently received this message from Facebook:

"Your application, "My App Name", is currently accessing Graph API v11.0 which will reach the end of its 2 year lifespan on September 14, 2023. To ensure a smooth transition please migrate all calls to Graph API v12 .0 or higher. Use the API Upgrade Tool to find out exactly how this change will impact your app.

Note: If you don't see any impacted calls in the API Update Tool, your app/code may not be affected by this update.

Please visit our changelogto see the complete list of changes across all versions of the Graph API."

Im using the last version from this SDK and others SDK are higher then 11.0:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2ZpC.png)

"react-native-fbsdk-next": "^11.2.1",
"react-native": "0.71.7",

Comment: SDK version is not necessarily the same, as the API version they communicate with.